# Creating a script that will automate filling out a form on an ad website

Tags: automation, web-scripting

I would like to create a script that would help me automate filling out a form on a website. Here is a basic idea that I came up with. The website consists of 5 stages.

1. Selecting a category and a group of an item
2. Adding the item. It consists of a title, price, etc...
3. Selecting the visibility
4. Finish putting out an ad by clicking I accept.
5. Deleting the previous ad of the same product

So basically what I had in mind was to sort all of my items in subfolders, each subfolder would contain an image of the item along with an info.txt file. The info.txt file would contain all the information that would be needed for filling out the form (for example title, price, text of the ad, etc...). Using these subfolders and .txt files I'd like to create a script that could help me add my items and fill out a from on an ad-based website.

So my question is: How to do this, what language/script should I use?

Comment: There are a number of webdriver-based tools that allow for programmatic browser manipulation like you've described (e.g. selenium-webdriver, webdriver.io, watir-webdriver). I'd suggest using one that maps to your language of choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). These tools are normally used for running unit tests for web apps in the browser, but I have used them before to do automated stuff on some websites as well. Selenium and PhantomJS are both operated by programming languages.

If you prefer a more simple approach and don't mind using proprietary apps, you could take a look at [iMacros](http://imacros.net/), although I am not sure if reading files is easy when using iMacros.